# 1 static IP, 2 web servers with 2 dns working with mod_proxy. Can I do the same with a CISCO router?

Tags: web-server, cisco, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I have:

- Cisco Router
- One static IP.
- 2 different Web servers with 2 domain names

I have configured a Apache reverse proxy with mod_proxy and is working ok but....

I´m investigating if its posible to do the same with a CISCO router. The router must inspect the HTTP domain header and do DNAT. I´m reading about Cisco Application Control Engine but cant find a clear example.

Help would be apreciated. Thanx

Comment: What specific Cisco device do you have?

Comment: Old 800 series ;)

Comment: @Luis What you're asking for is way beyond the capabilities of an 800 series router -- the kind of stuff you're looking for is the province of datacenter/carrier grade equipment (or if you want to avoid the price tag, homebrew proxy configurations like the one you apparently have in place now)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the kind of router you have.  Cisco 65xx series switches and 75xx series routers can do this and more [if you invest in the Content Switching Module (CSM)](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/modules/ps2706/ps780/index.html).  You can also buy [an 11500 series Content Services Switch (CSS)](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/contnetw/ps792/index.html) as a standalone solution.

Your local Cisco vendor will be thrilled to discuss all of your options (and how much they'll cost) with you.
Personally if everything is "working ok" as you said in your question I wouldn't make the investment until/unless you expect sufficient growth in the future to require the dedicated hardware (and to justify the cost).

Comment: Thank for answer @voretaq7. Can't understand why cisco doesn't provide this solution in small routers or switches. I think it's a common web server problem for small business. This can be acomplished with and old pentium machine and apache. Any other router brand?

Comment: Juniper Networks (juniper.net) may have something too - This isn't really a *router's* job though (at least not an IP router) -- It's a specialist task one (or more) layers further up in the OSI model.